# vectorを用いた構造体の参照渡し

Tags: c++

vectorを用いた構造体を他クラスで値を変更したいとき、どのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか。
下にコードの現状を書きます。

構造体

```
class st{
    struct hoge{
        int score1;
        int score2;
        int sum;
    }
}

class data{
public:
　　　　vector<TestScore>* Data::GetData(){
    return  &_studentScore;
　　　　}
}

class cal{
public:
    int sumCal(vector<hoge>* sScore){
        sScore[i]->sum = sScore[i]->score1 + sScore[i]->score2;
    }
}
```

上記コードのsumCal関数で構造体のscore1,2にアロー演算子でアクセスしようとすると、
式にはポインター型が必要ですと警告が出ます。
->*ではscore1は存在しないとエラーになります。

Comment: アクセスしたいところで具体的にどのようなコードを書いたかを、質問の編集で追加していただくと答えがつきやすくなります。

Answer (score 2):

質問タイトルには「参照」とありますが提示ソースコードは参照になっていないわけです。その辺で「参照」と「ポインタ」と「実体」の関係で混乱してしまっているようです。

提示ソースは関数 `sumCal` にて「 `vector` へのポインタ」を使っていますがたぶんこれが誤りで、本当にやりたいのは「 `vector` への参照」なのだろうと推測します。すると関数宣言は

```
int sumCal(vector<hoge>& sScore)
```

でなければなりません。そして `vector<hoge>` に格納されるのは `hoge` の値そのものなので、関数の中で `score1` などにアクセスするには `->` ではなくて `.` になります。結果

```
int sumCal(vector<hoge>& sScore) {
    sScore[i].sum = sScore[i].score1 + sScore[i].score2;
}
```

が書きたかったコードなのではないかな・・・と推測しました。

`i` がどこから来たのかとか `sumCal` の返却値が無いとかいろいろツッコミどころはありますが、その辺は本題から外れそうなのであえてスルーということで。